# JavaScript - How do I move href from li element and overwrite the href in h2 tag

Tags: javascript

My code:

```html
<section class="section">
  <h2 class="section-tree-title">
    <a href="{{url}}">{{name}}</a>
  </h2>
  <ul class="article-list">
    <li class="article-list-item">
      <a href="{{url}}" class="article-list-link">{{title}}</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>

<section class="section">
  <h2 class="section-tree-title">
    <a href="{{url}}">{{name}}</a>
  </h2>
  <ul class="article-list">
    <li class="article-list-item">
      <a href="{{url}}" class="article-list-link">{{title}}</a>
    </li>
    <li class="article-list-item">
      <a href="{{url}}" class="article-list-link">{{title}}</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

**Question**

The code above is dynamically generated on our zendesk system which lists sections and any articles they contain.

We want to manipulate this in javascript so the "li" tags are counted in each "section" class.
If the section only contains only 1 li element, then we want to take the url from that particular li tag and overwrite the url in the h2 tag. The `<ul>` block in that section then needs to be hidden as the link in the header is all that is required to locate the article.

Very weird I know but the purpose of this is to allow the user to access any single article directly.

Any help and advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I gave your sections a custom class `my-section`, so this code doesn't interfere with anything else you have going on.

```js
const sections = document.querySelectorAll('.my-section');

sections.forEach(section => {
    const sec_header = section.children[0];
    const sec_ul = section.children[1];
    
    if(sec_ul.children.length === 1) {
       // if we are here, it means there is only 1 "li"
       const only_li = sec_ul.children[0];
       sec_header.children[0].href = only_li.children[0].href;
       sec_ul.hidden = true;
    }
});
```

```html
<section class="section my-section">
  <h2 class="section-tree-title">
    <a href="header-1-url">{{name}}</a>
  </h2>
  <ul class="article-list">
    <li class="article-list-item">
      <a href="li-1.1-url" class="article-list-link">{{title}}</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>

<section class="section my-section">
  <h2 class="section-tree-title">
    <a href="header-2-url">{{name}}</a>
  </h2>
  <ul class="article-list">
    <li class="article-list-item">
      <a href="li-2.1-url" class="article-list-link">{{title}}</a>
    </li>
    <li class="article-list-item">
      <a href="li-2.2-url" class="article-list-link">{{title}}</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: This is perfect, you're my hero @Iraklis Gkougkousis! Thank you

Comment: Just be careful, if your html structure from the server changes, this code will break. Keep that in mind

Comment: I'm getting an error "Cannot read property 'children' of undefined" on some sections which don't dynamically generate an article list. Is there a way to by pass this error as it crashes the forEach loop. The code still works to some extent, I just don't know how to handle the error to prevent the loop crashing.

Comment: @DannyC Right before `const sec_header = ...` add this line: `if(section.childElementCount == 0) return;`

Comment: Still the same error I'm afraid. I couldn't help but notice some of the JS in your solution has been erased? You also provided an additional if statement that has been removed.    if(sec_ul.children.length > 1) {
      // if we are here, it means there are multiple "li" so we just need to hide the "ul"
      sec_ul.hidden = true;
    }

Comment: @DannyC I'm not sure what you mean. My post hasn't been edited at all, so nothing is missing here. Do you mean someone removed parts of it on your end? Anyway, I can help you if you provide some sample HTML of the situation you're facing. It's like I said though, if the HTML structure changes, the code will break.